# Unable to sign up in Rail 5.2 with devise

Tags: google-chrome, devise, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have an app that uses Devise gem, its works okay on firefox, but when trying to sign up using chrome it gives the following error.

```
The change you wanted was rejected.
Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

There is no Ajax request sent or whatever. It seems to be very strange.

Comment: I also use SSL certificate in my webpage.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this bug when I mess up with authenticity token in Firefox.

Comment: I also see this - rails 5.1 - I noticed it the day after installing ssl.
Also I have other things erroring - like an AJAX datatable.

Comment: This might help https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/a7t17k/cant_get_cookies_to_authenticate_in_rails_nginx/